# argument 2 to map() must support iteration while using celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I am calling the task as a group like this:

```
celery.group(getting_a_page.s(user, i,post) for i in range(no_of_pages))().get()
```

This is my task:

```
@task(ignore_result=True)
    def getting_a_page(user,page_no,post):

        print "getting a posterous page"

        return True
```

Where am I going wrong? What does this error mean?

Edit:

Error message:

```
/home/migrate/migrate/../migrate/apps/migrateuser/views.py" in start_migration
  72.   getting_a_page(user)
File "/home/migrate/migrate/apps/posting_app/posting.py" in posterours_get_pages_task
  21.   celery.group(getting_a_page.s(user, i,post) for i in range(no_of_pages))().get()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/canvas.py" in __call__
  316.                     map(Signature.clone, self.tasks), partial_args)
```

Comment: What's the `.s` here: `getting_a_page.s(user, i,post)`?

Comment: You should include your error message as well.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: See [the tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#guide-calling) in the "There’s another way..." sidebar.

Comment: Have you tried breaking this down into pieces to see which one is failing? First do `g = celery.group(getting_a_page.s(user, i,post) for i in range(no_of_pages))`, then `result = g()`, then `result.get()`. (Also see what `g.apply_async()` does.) Wherever it fails, please give us the traceback, not just one line out of it.

Comment: Have included the error message.

Comment: I did break it down and the problem was caused at: result = g()